# Determine for which $t\in \mathbb{R}$ the integral $\int_0^\infty \sin(x^t)\ dx$ converges!

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Obviously for $t=0$ the integral diverges.

For $t>1$ I have tried to subsitute $u=x^t$ and then split the integral up into segments of pi length such that I can write it as an alternating sum. Then (I think) I managed to prove that I can use Leibniz test since the alternating integrals get ever so smaller as $x \to \infty$.

Also for $x\in(0,1]$ I can bound the sine from below by inscribing ever increasing triangles thus proving that the sequence doesn't go to 0, which implies that the series is divergent.

Now for $t<0$ I am completely clueless, partly because the graph is vastly different in that case. Substituting $1/x = u$ gets ugly very quickly, so I didn't follow through.

I'd highly appreciate any ideas and solutions, particularly if they are more elegant than my tries so far have been :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627263/find-all-alpha-in-mathbbr-such-that-int-0-infty-sinx-alphadx-conv) and [this](https://math.nyu.edu/student_resources/wwiki/index.php/Advanced_Calculus%3a_2010_January%3a_Problem_1).

Comment: Unfortunately I must not use the Dirichlet for integrals for I have not learned it yet. But thank you for the great resources - odd that I didn't find them myself.

Comment: Ignore the second link, the first one gives you what you want. There is also a good way to search the site for specific math text, I believe it was written by a user of the site who got annoyed with the in built MSE search function. It's called [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/).

Comment: As I said, alas I cannot use the Dirichlet test.

Comment: The first link doesn't use the Dirichlet test?

Comment: yeah it does :) I keep seeing $\sin(x^t) \sim x^t$ for t<0, but don't get how this helps me prove divergence for $t \in [-1,0]$